# Closed form for multiple regression coefficients

Tags: regression

I've seen two forms for the estimated coefficients, wondering what the difference is (if there's any), or if I'm missing something:

from regression models book
$$b = (X'X)^{-1}(X'X)Y$$

from wikipedia and my lecturer
$$b = (X'X)^{-1}(X')Y$$

Comment: I doubt any regression models book has that formula for the coefficient, but $(X^\prime X)^{-1}(X^\prime X)Y=Y$, which is the original data, is not correct. The second formula is the correct Ordinary Least Squares estimator of $b$ when $(X^\prime X)^{-1}$ exists.

Comment: Which book has that first form? On which page?

Comment: When $X$ is an $n$ by $p$ matrix and $Y$ is an $n$ vector, $X'X$ must be a $p$ by $p$ matrix, making it abundantly clear that the term $(X'X)Y$ has no meaning when $p \ne n.$

Comment: applied linear regression models (kutner, nachtsteim, neter), 4th ed, bottom of p.223, must be a typo

Comment: It is also listed in the first printing's Errata... https://netfiles.umn.edu/users/nacht001/www/nachtsheim/ALRM4e%20First%20Printing%20Errata%2012-8-03.pdf